# Извлечь список файлов из директории

Tags: java, файлы

**Как извлечь файлы с директории и добавить их в список в порядке их добавления в папку**

**Так не работает**

```
File file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath());
  List<File> readFiles = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Как она добавились]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File[] readFiles = directory.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(readFiles, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } });
```